# Xpath to find following-sibling where two attributes match

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Want to build an XPath Query to find all following siblings of xml nodes where two attributes match.

```
<testsuites>
<testcase classname="john" name="login">
<testcase classname=john" name="login">
<testcase classname="peter" name="logout">
<testcase classname="peter" name="login">
</testsuites>
```

Here I want to only select following sibling of the node where `name` as well as `classname` both matches.

Following works but it doesn't matches the @classname attribute with the selected sibling.

```
(xmlstarlet ed -d '/testsuites/testcase[@name=following-sibling::testcase/@name and @classname=following-sibling::testcase/@classname]' < report.junit) > final.xml
```

My purpose is to find duplicate nodes where @name and @classname attribute matches, and then delete all except the one that is last in the order.

Answer (score 1):

It works better if xpath selects the first following sibling

```
//testcase[@classname=./following-sibling::*[1]/@classname and @name=./following-sibling::*[1]/@name]
```

Finds:

```
<testcase classname="john" name="login"/>
```

Making @name not match

```
//testcase[@classname=./following-sibling::*[1]/@classname and @name!=./following-sibling::*[1]/@name]
```

Finds:

```
<testcase classname="peter" name="logout"/>
```

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks @LMC.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept and/or upvote the answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath expression:

```
xml  ed -d  "//testcase[@classname=.//following-sibling::testcase/@classname][@name=.//following-sibling::testcase/@name]"
```